# How to pull docker image from github and build image in ec2?

Tags: docker, github

My actual requirement is pull docker image from GitHub and build a docker image in ec2 instance and push that image to ecr. So, am just trying to clear my first step by asking help to pull image from git, very new to all this.

Comment: Github doesn't store images. It only stores Dockerfiles, which you must build yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through each step you're asking about in your requirements:

1. Pull from GitHub - You won't pull a docker image from here, however you may pull a Dockerfile from here, which would be used to build an image. The command to do this would be just like cloning any other repository: `git clone <repository url>`
2. Build the image on ec2 - First you will need to have docker installed on the ec2 instance. Assuming you're running Ubuntu on your ec2 instance, follow the good instructions on Docker's page (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) [miror](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). Once docker is installed, navigate to the directory that has your Dockerfile in it (cloned from git) and type `docker build . --tag mytag`
3. Push the image to ecr - To do this, you need to have the amazon CLI installed on your box, and you need an ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from AWS IAM. Once you have these, configure your connection by storing them as environment variables, or by typing `aws configure` and entering them. Once your credentials are configured, log into ECR by typing `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email`, and then copy/pasting the command it gives you. (you can also put ` around it to skip the copying step). This will allow you to push to ecr using docker push.

Comment: This helped me, thanks! and after this i need to automate all of this, am thinking by using Jenkins i could automate this and do i need a script to automate this or jenkins could take care of it by commands used from docker? i know its a dumb question, actual requirement is, if any changes made to image/Dockerfile in Github it should trigger jenkins in building new image and jenkins should push it to ECR, as am new learning this process i've tried to understand it by going step to step

Comment: GitHub is a git repository, so you can have Jenkins's "poll scm" functionality periodically check GitHub for changes. On changes, you'd kick off a new Jenkins job, which would do all the steps from above (checkout git, build docker, push to ECR). If your EC2 is a persistent Jenkins slave, then you only need to install docker and aws cli once. You should use Jenkins credential stores for your access key and secret key so they aren't in your job in plaintext.

Comment: I have 2 questions here, 1) so i can use poll scm to check for changes in dockerfile? 2)  By "jenkins credentials stores for your access key and secret key" you mean the authentication key generated for ECR? or any other credentials?

Comment: Poll SCM will check if there are changes to your repo in general. You can set include and exclude rules if you want to make it only trigger on dockerfile changes. And for the credentials store I mean your access key id and secret access key from AWS, since you will need to login to ecr every build.

Answer (score -1):

To clarify some of the points:
Github: It is a web-based hosting service for version control using git. So you can not pull docker image from Github. 
To build a Docker image, you need Dockerfile. So you can fork the GitHub project which has this Dockerfile.

Then to build it on ec2, you can check out the project containing Dockerfile on ec2 server and build it using:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/
and then you can push it to any registry using:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/